# How to concatenate ORDER BY in sql

Tags: python, sql, database, concatenation

I am working on a GUI gird and sql. I have two GUI buttons that can be clicked depending on what order the user wants the information. The order can be by Employee `Last_name` or `First_name`, but not both. I am not sure how to use that. I am suppose to use concatenation, but am not sure how to.

Below is what I tried to do:

```
def sort_employees(self, column):
    try:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        display="SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY  '%" + column + "%' "
        cursor.execute(display)
        entry = cursor.fetchall()
        self.display_rows(entry)
```

Also, the code works fine if I only have on entry:

```
display="SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY Last_name"
```

Comment: Why '%" + column + "%' and not " + column + "... The % is a wildcard character holder most frequently used in LIKE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have `%` in your query string, it's possible you're confusing it with the [`%s` syntax for string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

```
display = "SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY  '%" + column + "%' "
```

It seems what you want is more like this:

```
display = "SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY " + column
```

Or, as I prefer:

```
display = 'SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY {column}'.format(column=column)
```

Of course be careful  creating queries like this, you're exposed to SQL security vulnerabilities.

It's better to use a parametrised query instead of string interpolation/concatenation, but I don't know which database interface you're using, but it's easy to find that by searching the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the `ORDER BY` clause takes, as arguments, a list of column names:

```
--correct 
ORDER BY firstname, lastname, age
```

It can also take function outputs:

```
--correct, sort names beginning with a Z first
ORDER BY CASE WHEN first name LIKE 'Z%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, firstname
```

In some db, putting an integer ordinal on will sort by that column, numbered from the left, starting with 1:

```
--correct, sort by 3rd column then first
ORDER BY 3,1
```

It does not take a list of strings that happen to contain column names:

```
--incorrect - not necessarily a syntax error but will not sort by any named column
ORDER BY 'firstname', 'lastname', 'age'
```

Nor does it take a string of csv column names:

```
--incorrect - again not necessarily a syntax error but won't sort on any of the named columns
ORDER BY 'firstname, lastname, age'
```

Your code falls into the latter categories: you're turning the column name into a string. This is wrong. The "not working sql" and the "working sql" are very different. Print the result of he concatenation to screen and look at them if you're having a hard time seeing it from the code